# drupal rss xml transformed has tags

Tags: xml, jsp, drupal, xslt, rss

I have a Drupal site setup. The rss that it sends out for the feed is simple, the page has one image and some text for testing.

In another environment - non Drupal - I am importing the feed on a jsp page with transforming the xml.

```
<c:import url="http://myfeedurl/rss.xml" var="inputDoc" scope="session"/>
<c:import url="drupal.xsl" var="stylesheet" />
<x:transform xml="${inputDoc}" xslt="${stylesheet}"/>
```

Everything works properly, as in grabbing the xml stream and rendering it on the page. However it is spitting out the html tags in the content. So instead of seeing "This is a test" I am seeing `<div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded"><p>This is a test</p> </div>`

I am wondering if this is a Drupal rss issue, or if I need something on my rendering end. I have done this before with other rss feeds and it displays properly.

When you view the source on the correct rss feeds the xml is all there in the tags as it is supposed to be.

When you view the source on this drupal feed it looks like this `&lt;div class=&quot;field-item even&quot; property=&quot;content:encoded&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;This is a test&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;` instead of html.

Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal is using HTML entities to preserve the tags. If you don't want that, you need to strip them on Drupal's side of things. The exact method depends on the way you generate the feed.

If you do want them, you need to decode the entities before rendering it, otherwise the escaped entities will show up as characters. You can use http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29 for this.

Comment: Is there a module recommendation for the drupal side? drupal 7.19....or do I just need to hack the core some place?

The feed is simply the built in rss for each page in drupal.

Comment: do you want to preserve the HTML formatting or have it just as plaintext? It would be preferable to just decode the HMTL entities (from my experience it's standard practice for most feeds). 

in case you want to force Drupal to use plain text for RSS, you need to go to the content type(s) included in the RSS feed, select "Manage Display", expand "Custom Display Settings", and check RSS. You should now have an additional tab for RSS settings. You can use "Plaintext" as a format option for your field(s).

Comment: I took what you said and applied it to my xsl stylesheet. I simply added the disable-output-escaping="yes" to the desired tags and it works properly without fuss.   Thanks for the help.